# How to show two results of two queries of mysql in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

This is my code and the result is wrong. I want to show the results of my first query in first column and results of second query in the 2nd column,but both results go in one (first) column. How can I have like this without changing the query?

```
/*
    username        username
    username_a_1    username_b_1
    username_a_1    username_b_4
    username_a_2    username_b_1
    username_a_2    username_b_4
    username_a_3    username_b_5
    username_a_4    username_b_2
    username_a_4    username_b_3
    username_a_5    username_b_1
    username_a_5    username_b_4
*/
<html>
<head></head>
<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <th>USERNAME</th>
        <th>USERNAME</th>
    </tr>
<?php
include'db_connect.php';

$query1='SELECT username FROM contacts_a ';
$query_run1=mysql_query($query1);

$query2="SELECT contacts_a.username,contacts_b.username FROM contacts_a LEFT JOIN contacts_b ON contacts_a.level=contacts_b.level";
$query_run2=mysql_query($query2);



 while($query_array1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)){
        foreach($query_array1 as $index => $names){

            echo   '<tr>
                        <td>'.(($names == NULL )? 'NULL': $names).'</td>
                   </tr>'; 
        }//end of foreach

  }//end of while

  while($query_array2=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run2)){

        foreach($query_array2 as $index => $names){

             echo   '<tr>
                      <td>'.(($names == NULL )? 'NULL': $names).'</td>
                    </tr>'; 
        }//end of foreach

  }//end of while




?>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). *They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)*. Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: You already have all the data you need in your second query: contacts_a.username is the username from the first query and contacts_b.username is the username from the second query. Just loop over the second set of data to print to your table.

Comment: ... and add an `ORDER BY` clause to that query to get the rows returned in a sequence that you specify, rather than allowing the database to return the rows in whatever order it wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Select the data, all together now. The difference is we'll give it a name
$query2="SELECT contacts_a.username as firstTableName, 
                contacts_b.username as secondTableName 
           FROM contacts_a 
      LEFT JOIN contacts_b 
             ON contacts_a.level = contacts_b.level";

// Execute the Query
$query_run2=mysql_query($query2);

// Loop over our results...
while($query_array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)) {
    // We're going to use this again, give it a good name
    $firstName = ($query_array1['firstTableName'] == NULL)   ? 'NULL' :
        $query_array1['firstTableName'];
    $secondName = ($query_array1['secondTableName'] == NULL) ? 'NULL' :
        $query_array1['secondTableName'];

    // Put out a new table row
    echo   '<tr>';
        // And our first TD...
       echo '<td>' . firstName  .'</td>';
       echo '<td>' . secondName .'</td>';
    echo   '</tr>'; 

// End our loop
} // So Long and Thanks for All the Fish!
```

Some other thoughts: [Don't use MySQL!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) You can also get rid of the first query now, as it's superfluous. Regarding your NULL checks, what happens if the data goes in as an empty string? Typically I check for null and for empty quotes: '' or "" just to make sure I get back what I want.

DISCLAIMER: I didn't actually try this, and I use PDO so my MySQL syntax for getting back and reading the MySQL array may be incorrect!

Comment: thanks for your answer but my big problem is how to fill two columns of table at the same time when i have 2 queries and while loop you wrote does n`t do that

Answer (score -2):

```
$qa1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1);
$qa2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run2);

do {
  echo   '<tr>
    <td>'.(current($qa1) == NULL ? 'NULL': current($qa1)).'</td>
    <td>'.(current($qa2) == NULL ? 'NULL': current($qa2)).'</td>
  </tr>'; 
} while( next($qa1) || next($qa2) );
```